# Mootools 1.3 window.addEvent('load') not working in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, mootools

I'm creating a Joomla module which loads some data from a slow source, so I used Ajax to load data after page completely load.
I used Joomla 1.7 native mootools library and as far as I know, there are two events, "domready" that works after page structure load and "load" that works after page elements loads but none of them are working in IE7-.

Info: I'm testing with IETester and IE9 compatibility mode.

My Code:

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    alert('page loaded!');
    var url = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
    var query = 'city1=<?php echo $city1; ?>&city2=<?php echo $city2; ?>&city3=<?php echo $city3; ?>&t=<?php echo $time; ?>';
    updateElement('weather', url, query);
});
```

and alert is not working in IE at all

Comment: Put up a test case on JsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was really stupid.

I added language="javascript" attribute in script tag and it worked!

it should be like this to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
```

not this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

or this:

```
<script>
```

Stupid IE!